# IAM Role Association to the available AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

As I'm an AWS newbie, I didn't know that I should tag the role while launching the AWS EC2 instance. After launching the AWS EC2 instance, I deployed an application now and get the following error on the console.

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:user/AWSAdmin is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::#########:role/myRole
```

any possiblities to edit the created instance and attach the role to make myApp running? any clue would be much helpful on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed on this topic.

It's true that an IAM Role could (formerly) only be attached to an EC2 instance *during* creation. This is repeated many times online in training content and in the AWS Certification exams.

As of 2/9/2017, AWS announced a new EC2 feature availability where an IAM Role could be attached to an currently *running* EC2 instance, removed from an EC2 instance, or replaced with a different IAM Role. Roles can still be specified during creation, but they can now also be altered at runtime.

See more: 
[AWS Blog Post on EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/02/new-attach-an-iam-role-to-your-existing-amazon-ec2-instance/)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

> You can't assign a role to an existing instance; you can only specify a role when you launch a new instance.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

Comment: Yep, Michael.  Thanks for reading my question.Now I'm cloaning my instance. :'(